# JOptionPane inside a while loop showing after the while loop is terminated

Tags: java, while-loop, joptionpane

So the programs successfully runs, except that when the while loop's termination condition is met, it will post the last JOptionPane input dialog before showing the message dialog to end the program, where the input dialog will accomplish absolutely nothing.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DiceGame2{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Dice[] dDice = new Dice[5];
    String[] sDice = new String[5];
    String finalSDice, sRoll;
    int diceTotal=1, oldTotal=0, iRoll, numberOfRolls=0;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        dDice[i]= new Dice();
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        dDice[i].roll();
    }
    while(diceTotal>=oldTotal){
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            sDice[i]=Integer.toString(dDice[i].value());
        }
        finalSDice=Arrays.toString(sDice);          
        oldTotal=diceTotal;
        diceTotal=0;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            diceTotal+=dDice[i].value();
        }
        sRoll=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Your 5 dice contain the numbers:\n"+finalSDice+"\nThese dice have a total score of "+diceTotal+".\nEnter which dice you would like to reroll to attempt to increase your score:");
        iRoll=Integer.parseInt(sRoll);
        dDice[iRoll-1].roll();
        numberOfRolls++;
    }
    finalSDice=Arrays.toString(sDice);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your 5 dice contain the numbers:\n"+finalSDice+"\nThese dice have a total score of "+diceTotal+".\nYou've failed to increase your total score.\n You made "+numberOfRolls+" successful rolls.");
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use JOptionPane in loop :).
You are creating frame in loop it is not good because you can't

Comment: I don't see where your code does this, can you show us input and output?

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper There's only two JOptionPane dialogs, and the program is an extremely simple dice counter.

Comment: Right, I'd like to see your input and output please

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate `diceTotal` immediately after rolling, so your while loop will exit sooner.

Comment: yep! that's exactly it